# How to read data from two files and merge the data into single file in apache nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

Hi I have two are more files in my filesystem now i want to check if two files names are same based on some condition and if two files names are same then i need to append the second file content into first file. Below are the files

```
12_345_hdr1.txt
12_345_hdr2.txt
34_123_hdr1.txt
34_123_hdr2.txt
```

let say first file has the below data

```
12_345_hdr1.txt
-------------
H 123
H ABC
H 799
```

and second file has the below data

```
12_345_hdr2.txt
-------------
H PAN
```

so first i need to check the files names are same or not based on the first and second part of the  file, let say first file has 12_345 and second file also has 12_345, so no i have to assume that both are same and now i need to push the second file content into fist file,in the same way third file and forth are same , can you please sugguest me the best approvach in apache nifi

Comment: do you have always pairs of files? or there are could be more/less then two?

Comment: yes always i have pairs of files, minimum two files and maximum any number of files

Comment: how do you know if all files from the same group are ready to be processed? for example there are files A1, A2 are present, but A3 is not written yet - how nifi could know that it should wait for file A3?

Comment: i will run the previous processor group first so it will get all the files and then i have to do the merging logic as i put in my first post

Comment: Mergecontent processor could solve the issue but it requires the number of files to expect to merge in each group. Unfortunately you don't have this information. Maybe you can add number of files in group to each file name? For example - A_1_3, A_2_3, A_3_3